# Custom Key Binding Overrides Windows Key Bind Function

Tags: c#, events

So I have created a menu strip and on my menu strip I have a button. The button has key bindings to it (Ctrl+V) so when you press those keys it will press the button. I have set these key bindings in the menu strip menu item short cut keys property.

The issue is that I am using a data grid view and that when I am modifying a cell (in edit mode) and use the Ctrl+V keys it does not paste my clip board.

Is it possible to retain the original windows function for that key binding in my program as well as having my own function for that key binding based on the circumstances of which it was used?

I've tried replicating the windows paste function for the data grid view, but it's not as perfect as I want it and I don't want to go about creating a custom control just to achieve this because I can simply just change the key binding for the button.

Comment: Don't use `ctrl+V` for any actions except Paste, it's only asking for trouble, and there are so many unused key combinations available for your button.

Comment: The thing is I have made a function to copy and paste cells. If I could use this for both the function and how it is used normally in text that would be awesome, if it's not possible I'll just look into using another key combination.